# Why do the police say "Freeze"?

Tags: word-in-context, word-play

Where does this originate? Why not say **Halt** or just **Stop** or something like **Stay put**?

I can understand the meaning of the word **Freeze** perfectly well.

Is it a classic word-play or just a set term for the police?

Comment: Have you done a search on your question? There are an amazing number of answers out there already.

Comment: This question seems like one purely on etymology, which might be better suited for ELU. It could be closed here.

Comment: @Peter I did, a little, usually people here can seek out much more information than there is out there.

Comment: They only say freeze in television shows.

Comment: I guess the police say “don't move” rather than "freeze" when arresting someone.

Comment: If I were a cop I'd always shout **Freeze!**

Comment: “Don't move" or "Stop” can be understood easily by foreigners unlike "freeze".

Answer (score 1):

Actually *freeze* is a more descriptive word in your context. See [*freeze*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/freeze):

> 6. verb
>      If someone who is moving freezes, they **suddenly stop** and become **completely still and quiet**.

As for the common usage, you would have to ask the police or investigate the etymology. My guess is that Hollywood is mostly responsible.

Comment: So you think Hollywood invented it?